# IIS 7.5 Redirct from HTTPS

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

I have multiple websites on my IIS 7.5 with one IP address and a wildcard SSL Certificates installed.
Now i want to change the wildcard certificate but i want if the user browse the old https web sites to redirected to the new https one.

How can i do that  in IIS 7.5?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

While you change the SSL certificate, URLs wont be changed. Hence, there would be nothing like Old HTTPS or New HTTPS and no need of redirection.

If you want to change the SSL certificate, you just need to install it in your all websites as you did earlier.

Comment: Thank you Jilesh for your response... i have two certificates installed one of them(all are sub domains) is applied to my websites... Now i will change the domain to a new one and will apply the new certificate.. but i want the iis to redirect the incoming requests from old http and https to the new one.